# How to add multiple textviews using textwatchers, if data is getting from another activities through intents

Tags: android

I am working on a budget app and I have multiple textviews and edittext in different activities. I have add multiple edittexts and take result through textwatchers and it is working fine with sharedpreferences.

Then I transfer results of each activity using intents and now I want to add all results in my mainactivity but unfortunately I have tried multiple times with different codes but not succeeded. I have also tried to create a method `addNumbers(){}` but whenever I placed textviews on this method activity stop showing intents.

MainActivity where I want to add all textviews:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {
private SharedPreferences.Editor editor;
TextView total, catering, OM;
Button btn;
private long backPressedTime = 0;
String OMtotal, mytext, total;

private Object TextWatcher;
SharedPreferences sharedPreferences;

@Override
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn);
    catering = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.catering);
    mytext = (getIntent().getStringExtra("mytext"));
    catering.setText(mytext);

    OM = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.omc);
    OMtotal = (getIntent().getStringExtra("OMtotal"));
    OM.setText(OMtotal);

total = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.total);
total.setText(total);


    CurvedBottomNavigationView mView = findViewById(R.id.customBottomBar);
    mView.inflateMenu(R.menu.bottom_menu);
    mView.setSelectedItemId(R.id.budget);
    //getting bottom navigation view and attaching the listener
    mView.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(MainActivity.this);

}

@Override
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.budget:
            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Catering.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            break;
        case R.id.food:
            Intent intent1 = new Intent(MainActivity.this, OtherMis.class);
            startActivity(intent1);
            break;
        case R.id.EEC:
            Intent intent2 = new Intent(MainActivity.this, reset.class);
            startActivity(intent2);
            break;
        case R.id.Venue:
            break;


    }
    return true;
}

public void addNumbers() {

    mytext = (getIntent().getStringExtra("mytext"));
    catering.setText(mytext);

    OMtotal = (getIntent().getStringExtra("OMtotal"));
    OM.setText(OMtotal);
return;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Shared preferences store date in the form of key-value pairs. So, you store all the values in the other activities into different keys and get them on the main activity. Intents work only if you start an activity along with some data being sent. In this case, intents might not help you.

Also, if you use intents, you must handle those intents in the `onBackPressed` of every activity you navigate to, which will be tedious. To know more about storing data in shared preferences and retrieving them in another activity, [check this out](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences).

If you have further questions regarding shared preferences, please share the code which you add data into the shared preference and I may be able to assist you only after that.